# Why does this Mathematica 7 Do loop work sequentially, but generates errors in parallel (using ParallelDo)?

Tags: parallel-processing, wolfram-mathematica, do-loops, mathematica-7

I am running Mathematica 7, and I am trying to run a simple `Do` loop in parallel, using `ParallelDo`.  The following standard, sequential code works fine:

```
len = 10;

A = Table[0, {len}];

Do[
 A[[i]] = i*10;
 , {i, 1, len}]
```

However, if I use `ParallelDo` instead of the standard `Do`, this code gives error messages:

```
len = 10;

A = Table[0, {len}];

ParallelDo[
 A[[i]] = i*10;
 , {i, 1, len}]
```

The error messages that I get are:

```
Set::noval: Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
Set::noval: Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
Set::noval: Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
Set::noval: Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
Set::noval: Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
Set::noval: Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
General::stop: Further output of Set::noval will be suppressed during this calculation.
General::stop: Further output of Set::noval will be suppressed during this calculation.
Set::noval: Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
Set::noval: Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
Set::noval: Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
Set::noval: Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
```

Is there anything I can do to run this **Do** loop in parallel?

Thank you!

Andrew DeYoung

Carnegie Mellon University

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get no errors on Mathematica 8.0.1.0.

However, the code probably doesn't do what you intended, because `A` is copied to each subprocess (and changes are local to that subprocess). Hence

```
ParallelDo[A[[i]] = i*10; Print@A, {i, 1, len}]
```

prints

[image: Mathematica result]

and the final result is `A` = {0, 0, ..., 0}.

Instead, you should add `SetSharedVariable[A]` after initializing `A`. The result is now `{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100}`, as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Any reason not to use a `ParallelTable`?

```
ParallelTable[i*10,{i, 1, len}]
```